# I was trying to add a balance system in my JAVA program, but i failed

Tags: java, android

As a new programmer, I don't know how methods are really works. But when I used `Object`, can they give me any int, float or double value? And can it be used as integer, float, double!?  Please help me. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectBookShop {
static Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

static String[] books = {"Java", "C", "CSS"};
static final double studentDiscount = 0.3;
static final double teacherDiscount = 0.4;
static final double alienDiscount = 0.0;
static final int balance = 150;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    prln("<---- WELCOME TO OUR BOOK SHOP --->");
    prln("Today we are offering you" +balance + "Taka");
    prln("Which books do you want:\n Ans:");
    String usersChoice= scan.nextLine();

    if(books[0].toLowerCase().equals(usersChoice.toLowerCase()))
    {
        prln("You opted for Java.");
        calculatePrice(books[0]);

       //Problem starts from this line.
        if(balance => showPrice(calculatePrice(books[0])))
        {
            prln("You are eligible for buying this book!");
        }


    }else if(books[1].toLowerCase().equals(usersChoice.toLowerCase()))
    {
         prln("You opted for C.");
         calculatePrice(books[1]);
    }else if(books[2].toLowerCase().equals(usersChoice.toLowerCase()))
    {
        prln("You opted for Css.");
        calculatePrice(books[2]);
    }
    else
    {
        prln("We dont have this book.");
    }

}
// These are called methods!

static void calculatePrice(String bookName)
{
    double price = 200;
    prln("Are you a student, teacher or alien:\n Ans:");
    String answer = scan.nextLine();
    if(answer.toLowerCase().equals("student"))
    {
        price = price - (price*studentDiscount);
        showPrice(price);

    }else if(answer.toLowerCase().equals("teacher"))
    {
        price = price - (price * teacherDiscount);
        showPrice(price);
    }else if(answer.toLowerCase().equals("alien"))
    {
    price = price - (price * alienDiscount);
    showPrice(price);
    }else
    {
    prln("We dont offer any books for you!!");
    showPrice(price);
    }

}
static void showPrice(Object price)
{
prln("Your total price will be: "+ price);
prln("<---- Thanks for shoping with us. --->");
}

static void prln(Object anyObject)
{
    System.out.println(anyObject);
}

static void pr(Object anyObject)
{
    System.out.print(anyObject);
}
}
```

Comment: The method `showPrice` does not return any value. Therefore, it cannot be used in a comparison. Actually, `calculatePrice` doesn't return a value either, so it cannot be used as a parameter to `showPrice`. And `calculatePrice` calls `showPrice`, so that may be an issue as well.

Comment: `return price` from `calculatePrice` and use it as your comparison. That is actually step 2, step 1 (unfortunately) is to read up on the fundamentals of Java. It will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: Aaah!! Started this project before learning return types!! :( I thought that it could be easy!! By the way, Thanks for helping!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **primitive types** like `int`, `double` or `boolean` can be assigned to `Object`s. It is done using **wrapper types**:

- `byte` - `Byte`
- `short` - `Short`
- `int` - `Integer`
- `long` - `Long`
- `float` - `Float`
- `double` - `Double`
- `char` - `Character`
- `boolean` - `Boolean`
- `void` - `Void`
  Note `Void` is special. As `void` has no value, the only value assignable to `Void` is `null`.

`Object`s cannot be used as primitive types unless you **cast** them to right type:

```
Object ob = myObjectStream.readObject();
Integer intg = (Integer) ob;
```

Warning: attempting to cast a `float` wrapped as `Float` and assigned as `Object` to `Integer` will result in `ClassCastException` being thrown. To prevent it, you may use `instanceof`:

```
Object ob = myObjectStream.readObject();
if(ob instanceof Integer) {
  int x = (Integer) ob;
  // Do something
} else if(ob instanceof Float) {
  float f = (Float) ob;
  // Do something else
} else {
  System.err.println("I don't support provided object class!!!");
}
```

Did you notice an assignment to `float` from `Float`? This works in both sides:

```
float x = 1.0f;
Float y = x;
float z = y; // == 1.0f
```

That is **automatic boxing/unboxing**. If you don't want to use it, you may still do it by hand:

```
float x = 1.0f;
Float y = Float.valueOf(x);
float z = y.floatValue(); // == 1.0f
```

This works for all wrapper types except `Void`.

---

Also, instead of:

```
String s1, s2;
if(s1.toLowerCase().equals(s2.toLowerCase()) {
  // ...
}
```

Use:
    String s1, s2;
    if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2) {
      // ...
    }
This deals properly with some corner-case Unicode characters.

---

Operator `=>` does not exist. Did you mean `>=`?

---

If method `showPrice` is always given `double`s, wrapped into `Double`s, there's no sense to make it wrap them; wrapping takes time. If it is given only `Double`s, rewrite it to following:

```
static void showPrice(double price)
{
prln("Your total price will be: "+ price);
prln("<---- Thanks for shoping with us. --->");
}
```

This works the same and is faster.

---

`pr` is never used! Remove it and save code. Also, when class is loaded, all its methods are loaded. So, if you remove it, you can also make your program boot faster.

---

As some comments suggest, you try comparing `void`. Rewrite `showPrice` once again:
    static double showPrice(double price)
    {
    prln("Your total price will be: "+ price);
    prln("<---- Thanks for shoping with us. --->");
    return price;
    }
This makes the comparison work.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use Object for your method arguments. Object is the base Object that every other object in Java is derived from, but in your case, when a parameter is passed (such as a double) to a method that has an Object argument, the receiving method no longer "sees" it as a double, so it can not interpret it as a number.

You should change your `prln` and `pr` methods and instead use:

```
static void showPrice(double price)
{
    prln("Your total price will be: "+ price);
    prln("<---- Thanks for shoping with us. --->");
}

static void prln(String str)
{
    System.out.println(str);
}

static void pr(String str)
{
    System.out.print(str);
}
```